# Odd screen ratio phenomena

Tags: html, css, debugging, browser

I have an odd issue where the screen ratio is shown in the top most right corner of the web browser. It happens in every browser on every computer and I can't seem to find the issue in the code. Have anyone ever experienced this? What could it be? This is how the issue is displayed on the screen.

[image]

The text 16:9 is not targetable nor present in the code as far as I know.

Comment: I guess this is restricted to one website? Yours? What is the website made with? More info please.

Comment: The website is made with HTML, css, bootstrap, some Javascript and Php. mainly hand coded. The issue is only on this website.

Comment: Care to share the URL? Then I could inspect it (with the developer tools) and see what causes this. Something you could do yourself as well. Press F12 in a desktop browser on Windows, or right-click when the cursor is over the 16:9 text and choose 'inspect' or something similar.

Comment: In a CSS file called 'desktop.css' there this rule on line 129: `header::after { content: '16/9'; }`.

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution too!

Comment: haha, see, it can be found... nice site, by the way.